# Remove <option> by .class AND when custom attribute NOT equal to x

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

## What I have:

I have a select element. Some of the options have both a class (`.filterable_option`) and custom attribute (`data-clienturn`).

## What I need:

Based on the on change event of another element, I need to remove options from the select element that:

1. ...are classed as `.filterable_option`.
2. ...have a data-customattribute value NOT EQUAL TO the value of a predefined variable (`var = $some_value`).

## My code:

**HTML:**

```
<select name="myselect_a">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Apply filter">Apply filter</option>    
</select>

<select name="myselect_b">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option data-customattribute="58" value="1" class="filterable_option">Dog</option>    
    <option data-customattribute="58" value="2" class="filterable_option">Cat</option>
    <option data-customattribute="60" value="3" class="filterable_option">Parrot</option>
    <option>I have no class or custom attribute.</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#myselect_a').on('change', function() {
    var $myselect_a_option = $("#myselect_a").val();
    if($myselect_a_option === 'Apply filter'){  
        var $some_value = '58';
        $("select[name=myselect_b] option.filterable_option[data-customattribute!=" + $some_value + "]").remove();
    }
});
```

**JSFiddle:**

For your convenience: http://jsfiddle.net/clarusdignus/L82UH/

## My problem:

My code is not removing the required in options. Nothing happens.

Comment: +1 for the presentation of the question

Comment: as Neel Said +1 for the Presentation

Comment: That's a really nice presentation for a so simple error ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have used a name in your selector. Use an id instead as shown below

```
<select id="myselect_a">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Apply filter">Apply filter</option>    
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L82UH/1/

Or if you still want to go for name, try the below code:

```
$('select[name="myselect_a"]').on('change', function() {
  //your code 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, not sure why someone downvoted you. Either change the select attribute, or change the selector I guess.

Comment: @Neel Not sure what you mean but `.on()` works on all jQuery version since 1.7

Comment: sorry @A.Wolff it was misunderstanding created by me

Comment: `select[name="myselect_a"]` is much slower than using an ID

Comment: @JoshWillik - Since PHP selects my elements by name, I'm also using name as a jQuery selector (`name="foo"`). This is an attempt to avoid unnecessarily bulky mark-up by reiterating the same value for id as for name (`name="foo" id="foo"`). In spite of this, is it still quicker or considered better practice to use both name and id? How negligible/significant is the difference between both approaches?

Comment: @ClarusDignus code in my answer didn't work for you?

Comment: @ClarusDignus specifying an ID is useful not only for performance reasons, but it allows elements to be anchored, and will allow labels reference them.

Comment: @Matthew - Thanks. Based on your response, I'll revise my approach and forgo avoiding defining ids whenever names are already in place.

Comment: @Neel - It did. I just like to take my time judiciously deliberating and musing which member best answered my question. It may be a latent form of OCD :-)

Answer (score 4):

You have wrong selector for select and also following bit is corrected:
`name='myselect_b']`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/L82UH/2/

```
$('select[name="myselect_a"]').on('change', function() {
    var $myselect_a_option = $(this).val();
    if($myselect_a_option === 'Apply filter'){  
        var $some_value = '58';
        $("select[name='myselect_b'] option.filterable_option[data-customattribute!=" + $some_value + "]").remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for the selector, but quotes are not required for attribute selectors

Comment: quotes are required if the attribute value contains more than one word. just use that, its a kind of good practice.

Comment: @A.Wolff It's not a dynamic value though, I should have said for *this* attribute selector

Comment: @RGraham Ya, just understood what you meant

Comment: +1. Thank you for your answer. I opted for Neel's answer since he chronologically answered three minutes earlier. I was originally opting for your answer since it honored my mark-up convention (use of names instead of ids) however Neel updated his answer to incorporate both conventions.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy check this question ( and answers ) regarding your comment above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812040/getting-amount-of-checkboxes-checked-by-name/23812084?noredirect=1#comment36630968_23812084

Answer (score 1):

See you have name attribute in your markup:

```
<select name="myselect_a">
```

and you are using a id selector:

```
$('#myselect_a')
```

this is the issue.