# Getting amount of checkboxes checked by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked

I'm trying to find out how many checkboxes have been checked but am having some trouble..

My checkboxes are all named `delete[]`.

```
var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name=delete]:checked').length);
```

...and this doesn't work at all:

```
var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name=delete[]]:checked').length);
```

Comment: just wrap delete[] in double quotes in your second example like `var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name="delete[]"]:checked').length);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply wrap delete[] in double quotes in your second example like this:

```
var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name="delete[]"]:checked').length);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the square brackets. Try this:

```
var count = $('#form_store_setup input[name=delete\\[\\]]:checked').length;
```

Or put the attribute value in quotes:

```
var count = $('#form_store_setup input[name="delete[]"]:checked').length;
```

Comment: or `var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name="delete[]"]:checked').length);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not have any other named items, that begin with `delete`, you can use the "starts with" matching:

```
var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name^=delete]:checked').length);
```

Comment: what if a checkbox has a name for example `delete_this` :/

Comment: Just a suggestion, it does depend on what else is on the page... Bit puzzled why they have `delete[]` in the first place :) Updated answer to qualify usage only if no other `delete...` elements present.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie it's used in PHP to send a group of element values as an array.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Ah, MVC does similar, but you get the index value as well in the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. Try adding single quotes around your input name. Also you can call .size() instead of .length for the same effect.

```
var count = ($('#form_store_setup input[name='delete[]']:checked').length);
```

See this document for reference regarding the size() function (http://api.jquery.com/size/)

Comment: Single quotes inside single quotes... busted! :)