# VB.net will a function run if something else is running

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net application using windows forms.

In the application, I have a few functions that run on timers.

Can you tell me, if something is in process on the application and a time kicks in whilst it is running will the function that the timer run take over the current process?

Comment: Is your timer a Windows.Forms timer or a System.Timers timer?

Comment: @hatchet Sounds like a windows.forms timer

Comment: A mandatory reading [Comparing The Timer Classes in the NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx)

Comment: its saying System.Windows.Forms.Timer if that helps? Its just a timer from under Components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Windows.Forms.Timer runs the `Tick` on the UI thread.

You can only run one thing at a time on each thread.

Therefore, if you are running something, even from a previous timer tick, the next tick will not run until your UI thread is idle.

Answer (score 1):

Some timers are synchronous, and some are asynchronous.

Here is an excerpt from the MSDN Library regarding timers:

- [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), which fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), which executes a single callback method on a thread pool thread at regular intervals. The callback method is defined when the timer is instantiated and cannot be changed. Like the System.Timers.Timer class, this class is intended for use as a server-based or service component in a multithreaded environment; it has no user interface and is not visible at runtime.
- [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), a Windows Forms component that fires an event and executes the code in one or more event sinks at regular intervals. The component has no user interface and is designed for use in a single-threaded environment.
- [System.Web.UI.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), an ASP.NET component that performs asynchronous or synchronous web page postbacks at a regular interval.